# find max value for specific column while still seeing other columns

Tags: postgresql, max

For tables patient and labh

```
patient
id  lastname
19  patientone
20  patienttwo
```

```
patientid   lastname    loinc   datetime            numerical  
19  patientone  4548-4  2014-05-15 00:00:00 6.5
19  patientone  4548-4  2015-05-15 00:00:00 7.5
19  patientone  4548-4  2016-05-15 00:00:00 3.5
19  patientone  4548-4  2017-05-15 00:00:00 5.5
19  patientone  5000-3  2018-05-15 00:00:00 123
20  patienttwo  4548-4  2013-05-15 00:00:00 2.5
20  patienttwo  4548-4  2012-05-15 00:00:00 1.5
20  patienttwo  4548-4  2011-05-15 00:00:00 9.5
20  patienttwo  4548-4  2010-05-15 00:00:00 3.5

Desired output:
patientid   lastname    datetime            numerical  
19  patientone  2017-05-15 00:00:00 5.5 
20  patienttwo  2013-05-15 00:00:00 2.5
```

The labh table hold lab values(numerical), the type of lab (loinc) and when they were done (datetime).  I'd like to query for the most recent value of loinc=4548-4 , and i'd like the output to show both the date and the value.

i've tried this below and it shows the most recent dates, but I can't see the values (numerical) at the same time.  when I add the numerical column, the it shows all the values, not just the most recent.

```
Select Distinct patient.id, patient.lastname, Max(Date_Trunc('day', labh.datetime)) As "Date" From  patient Inner Join labh On patient.id = labh.patientid Where labh.loinc = '4548-4' Group By patient.id, patient.lastname, patient.firstname Order By patient.id
```

Comment: I forgot to include that within the labh table there are other types of labs, defined by LOINC code .  In this case I only care about the 4548-4 code.  I'm sorry for the oversight. I will edit my post.

Comment: [`distinct on()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you haven't selected the numerical column in your query. You can use CTE to store the data temporarily through ranking on pratition over patient id and ordering each partition on the basis of date.

So, according to this, you can try:

```
WITH summary AS (
SELECT  p.id as "Patient ID", 
        p.lastname as "Patient Name",
        l.datetime As "Date",
        l.numerical as "Numerical", 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.id 
                             ORDER BY l.datetime DESC) AS rank
  FROM patient p
        Inner Join labh l 
        On p.id = l.patientid)

 SELECT     "Patient ID", 
            "Patient Name",
            "Date",
            "Numerical"
 FROM summary
 WHERE rank = 1;
```

And this will give you:

| Patient ID | Patient Name | Date | Numerical |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19 | patientone | 2017-05-15T00:00:00.000Z | 5.5 |
| 20 | patienttwo | 2013-05-15T00:00:00.000Z | 2.5 |

**UPDATE**

As you've updated the question and changed the expectation, the modified query will be nothing but adding a where condition inside cte construction:

```
WITH summary AS (
SELECT  p.id as "Patient ID", 
        p.lastname as "Patient Name",
        l.datetime As "Date",
        l.numerical as "Numerical", 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.id 
                             ORDER BY l.datetime DESC) AS rank
  FROM patient p
        Inner Join labh l 
        On p.id = l.patientid
        where l.loinc = '4548-4')             -- Added this line

 SELECT     "Patient ID", 
            "Patient Name",
            "Date",
            "Numerical"
 FROM summary
 WHERE rank = 1;
```

This will give you the same result:

| Patient ID | Patient Name | Date | Numerical |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19 | patientone | 2017-05-15T00:00:00.000Z | 5.5 |
| 20 | patienttwo | 2013-05-15T00:00:00.000Z | 2.5 |

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Unfortunately I left off that there are more than one type of lab within this table, so this looks like it should give me the most recent lab, but that won't necessarily be the right type of lab.  I updated my table in my original question.

Comment: @Socram, Updated my answer in the UPDATE section. Just added the condition in CTE. It works as per your expectation. Please check

Comment: Thank you, this appears to do what I need it to .  I've not used WITH in the past, does that change anything in how this would work with regards to EXCEPT?  I'm trying to take this query and EXCEPT other things out from it (the values that are <3mo old, and the values that are both <6mo old and under 8 - leaving all values over 6 mo old and high (>8) values over 3 mo old).  I have 2 queries for these.  The EXCEPT doesn't seem to work as I would have expected.  Since I'm not used to WITH, I wondered if that might have something to do with it? (or i need to rewrite what im doing)

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve what you're looking for in Postgres (and other SQL RDBMSes), you need to essentially identify the max value and its corresponding primary key, then join it with the rest of the data set you are looking to retrieve:

```
SELECT patient.*, labh.*
  FROM patient
  JOIN labh
    ON patient.id = labh.patientid
  JOIN (SELECT patientid, max(datetime)
          FROM labh
      GROUP BY patientid) maxvals
    ON maxvals.patientid = labh.patientid AND
       maxvals.datetime = labh.datetime
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Unfortunately I left off that there are more than one type of lab within this table, so this looks like it should give me the most recent lab, but that won't necessarily be the right type of lab.  I updated my table in my original question.